# "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lfacade/UserDAOLocal;" error in EJB

Tags: java, deployment, jvm

I have the following error on deployment of my EJB app. This may be caused by adding "L" to class path - package name is "facade", then I don't know where this "L" come from. Anybody knows where it can be added?

Answer (score 0):

This is from the JVM specification. Take a look here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.3.2

> The characters of BaseType, the L and ; of ObjectType, and the [ of ArrayType are all ASCII characters.

It defines how fields are stored, for `ObjectType` it is `L<ClassName>;`